# Repeat runs from a test suite only displays the final run in eclipse JUnit view

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have test suite with around 100 tests, and it needs to be run with different configuration, I looked at Theories and Parameterized tests, however they are repeated for each and every test, which is very expensive in my case. So I went ahead and created a custom TestSuite to setup the config once and run all the tests, then setup the next config and run all the tests ...
However the Junit window displays only the last run and I am unable to find out the test that failed in a previous run https://pasteboard.co/IsyA71q.png 
Is there a way to display all the repeated runs from the suite in the Junit window in eclipse?

I've looked around 
org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier with little luck

```
public class ExtendedSuite extends Suite
{
   public ExtendedSuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError
   {
      super(klass, builder);
   }

   @Override
   protected void runChild(Runner runner, RunNotifier notifier)
   {
      Object newInstance = null;
      try
      {
         newInstance = super.getTestClass().getJavaClass().newInstance();
      }
      catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      List<RepeatConfig> repeatConfigs = super.getTestClass()
            .getAnnotatedFieldValues(newInstance, ConfigureSuite.class, RepeatConfig.class);

      for (RepeatConfig repeatConfig : repeatConfigs)
      {
         repeatConfig.beforeSuiteRun();
         super.runChild(runner, notifier);
         repeatConfig.afterSuiteRun();
      }
   }
}
```

```
public interface RepeatConfig
{
   void beforeSuiteRun();

   void afterSuiteRun();
}
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Inherited
public @interface ConfigureSuite
{
}
```

```
@RunWith(ExtendedSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ MessagingTest.class })
public class AllTests
{
   @ConfigureSuite
   public RepeatConfig withConfig1 = new RepeatConfig()
   {

      @Override
      public void beforeSuiteRun()
      {
         System.out.println("beforeSuiteRunwithConfig1");

      }

      @Override
      public void afterSuiteRun()
      {
         System.out.println("afterSuiteRunwithConfig1");

      }
   };
   @ConfigureSuite
   public RepeatConfig withConfig2 = new RepeatConfig()
   {

      @Override
      public void beforeSuiteRun()
      {
         System.out.println("beforeSuiteRunwithConfig2");

      }

      @Override
      public void afterSuiteRun()
      {
         System.out.println("afterSuiteRunwithConfig2");

      }
   };

}
```

```
public class MessagingTest
{

   static int count = 0;

   @BeforeClass
   public static void setUp()
   {
      System.out.println("setting up");
   }

   @AfterClass
   public static void tearDown()
   {
      System.out.println("tearing down");
   }

   @Test
   public void testMessage1()
   {
      System.out.println("Executing test1");
      count++;
      if (count == 1)
         Assert.fail();
   }

   @Test
   public void testMessage2()
   {
      System.out.println("Executing test2");
   }
}
```

I would like to see the individual test results from all the runs in the junit window from eclipse so that I can narrow down the specific config, test pair for debugging purposes.

Comment: Are you aware that `@BeforeClass` is only executed once if you have a parameterized test? The `@Before` method is executed for every test. So why do you need the overhead and fragmentation of test suites etc.? You want tests to be as independent as possible, otherwise refactoring will be hell.

Comment: @MichielLeegwater To make myself more clear, the tests require a specific set of configuration, that's done in BeforeClass and AfterClass. Now there are different configurations at the domain/system/integration level that routes the messages differently, but the expected behavior from a system/integration/domain/black box perspective is the same, it should reach the intended recipients, it might have used different compression logic, different server to process internally among many others.

Comment: Maybe I am over complicating this, as @MichielLeegwater mentioned I can have different independent suites with it's own BeforeClass methods for system level configuration.